# How to play 8 different video files with 8 different laptops starting at the exact same time?

Tags: multiple-monitors, sync, video-playback

I have a project where I need to play 8 different video files on 8 TVs all in sync.

I was wondering if I could somehow use 8 laptops and sync them?

Comment: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/MPlayer.html#networksync

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? This is, currently, a very broad question requesting a significant amount of information but demonstrating no effort or information collection effort on your part yet.

Comment: is this for a video wall where the video is expanded to cover multiple monitors?